# Decompress files in subfolders to the same subfolder using 7-Zip

Tags: windows, command-line, compression, 7-zip

I have a set of subfolders with .gz files buried in them.  I need to decompress the files and keep the directory structure the same.  I have used

```
for /f "usebackq" %i in (`dir *.gz /s/b`) do 7za x %i
```

which will find the files and decompress them but sends the decompressed files to the root of the folder instead of keeping them in the directory they were found. Could someone tell me how I can decompress the files to the folders they were found?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have `C:\dir1\dir2` and dir2 and its sub-directories contain the .GZ files, run the following from `C:\dir1`:

```
for /r "dir2" %a in (.) do 7za x -o"%~a" "%~a\*.gz"
```